# How to do an event when uitext field is being typed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

How to do an action when Typing occured in UITextField ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set your UITextField's delegate to your class.

If you want to call an event as soon as user types anything implement this method,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
     NSLog(@"call your method");
    [self goMethodCall];
    return YES;
}
```

If you want somthing other than this, you have few more delegates.

There are few delegates that are invoked automatically...

```
– textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:
– textFieldDidEndEditing:
– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
– textFieldShouldClear:
– textFieldShouldReturn:
```

In any of the method call your action.

Find suitable for you.. [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Comment: It would help if you pointed out which one actually answers the question. :)

Comment: They all answer the ambiguous question.

Comment: @MechIntel What's ambiguous? He asked how to detect when someone is typing into a text field. That's pretty clear to me. Only one of the listed delegate methods is relevant to that question.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya Thanks alot brother,you are so helping

Comment: Actually I left from my office, so I didn't saw the comments. And your question was not clear what you actually want to do. Before Typing, while typing, after typing... so i posted all the delegate methods... so that you can choose from. Even rmaddy answer is good. Its your wish whose answer to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to be notified when the text of a text field has changed:

1. Implement the `UITextField` delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`
2. Register for the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` notification.
3. Add an action/target for the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` control event on the text field.